# Datetime issue with the streamlit dataframe display

Tags: python, python-3.x, datetime, streamlit

I am building a streamlit application and I am uploading an excel file to the Streamlit. However, when the data is displayed in a datetime format using `st.dataframe()`, it changes format and I am not able to fix it in dsiplay.

As you can see here, the interval column has these numbers and the Date column has time added to it which I want to fix.

[image]

The actual data looks a bit like this and this is how I would like to display data. I don't mind converting it to a string so we can use `strftime()` but I am sort of stuck in trying to implement that to my data.

[image]

Here's what my upload code looks like:

```py
# File Upload
uploaded_file = st.file_uploader(
    "Upload inventory file for past week estimates in **excel** format."
)

sheet_name = st.text_input("Add the name of the sheet to select data from. **Default = first sheet**")

# File processing button
# if st.button("Process file inputs"):
if uploaded_file is not None:
    
    try: 
        # Read the uploaded excel file
        if sheet_name: 
            historical_interval_data = pd.read_excel(uploaded_file, sheet_name=sheet_name)
        else: 
            historical_interval_data = pd.read_excel(uploaded_file)
    
        st.dataframe(historical_interval_data)
        
    except ValueError: 
        st.error("**Error**: The sheet name is incorrect.")
```

Comment: Did you try converting the date column to a datetype? Eg) df['Date'] = pd.to_datetime(df['Date'])

Comment: Yup, I did. I found a fix for the date but can't fix the time format. Can fix date like this - `output_format_data['Date'] = output_format_data['Date'].apply(lambda x: datetime.strftime(x, format="%Y-%m-%d"))`

Comment: What format is the time currently in? Have you tried `to_pydatetime`?